# open database of elementary, middle, and high schools in Latin America, Africa and Asia?

Tags: data-request, openstreetmap

Is there an up-to-date and regularly maintained open database of elementary, middle, and high schools in the South America and Africa?
I'm looking for both public and private schools. Names alone would be a good start, but of course addresses (at least a state and city).  Street-names and house-numbers would be great too. And phone numbers would be very useful.

Note; Sure there is the Dataset at openStreetmap which may provide a good starting-point. But perhaps there are some othter options too. Please post everything you have.

**updates ; regarding the total count of new entries in openstreetmap**

Some days before i have heard that it is interesting to have a closer look at the taginfo-site (see below): i have question: what does this mean https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=school

here we have two requests on the above site:

a. `today Objekts all 592852`

b. `three days ago: 2014-06-23 23:58`
   **all objects:**  592672 0.02% -
    [Node] Node 325997 - 0.36%
    [Way] Way 260585 - 0.11%
    [Relation] Relation 6090 - 0.23%

c. some (guess five) days before: we have had the following values:

```
all objetcts: 592 443 0.02%
[Node] Node 325 974 0.36%
[Way] Way 260 384 0.11%
[Relation] Relation 6 085 0.23%
```

see some more details - several days before

```
all: 592 443 0.02%:
```

you see: that differs: we have a difference of several hundred x (entries, records or some what)

**question:**
a. is it true that we can see the diff - that means how the entries of schools grow? b. is there a total growth of records (!!!) of schools or does the this mean - some records have been changed!?

look forward to hear from you

Comment: School data is sometimes handled as part of the countries census demographic data. Otherwise, it would be collected by the country's Dept. of Education. You will need to check country-by-country if this information is collected.

Comment: The reason for the change on the taginfo is because OSM is a continuually updated project, and data is being updated all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Education Policy and Data Center (EPDC) collects and summaries education related data from 200 countries in the world. While I don't believe they publish school location data, they do publish the sources of their data, which include link's to the countries dept. of education, census/demographic data, etc.

http://www.epdc.org/about-help/data-sources

Comment: many thanks for the information - this link to the epdc looks pretty nice. Guess that it helps me alot

Comment: @zero - You may want to check out my crowd-sourced catalog of open data portals (700 entries) as another reference. I added the education portals from EPDC to the list.

Comment: hello dear Andrew - i would love to see the catalog. Just let me see where it is!? Cant wait to see it - greetings zero update: http://www.opengeocode.org/ - ahh yes check it later theweekend  ;-) greetings

Comment: @zero - here's the link to the data portal catalog.

Comment: Manx many thanks  - great i will digg deeper the weekeend - btw . i added a question in the threadstart. See the question regarding the count of entries on osm-files. Are they total new entries!? Love to hear from you - btw - i am couriouis to get more countries with school data. and at the weekend i will have a closer look at your site,. many many thanks for all you do - did !!

Comment: added a update to the question - regarding the count of the shools in osm-database. the global osm-file. love to hear from you

Comment: Here's the direct link to the catalog (currently 900 entries): http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Answer (score 0):

For data from South Africa published by the South African Department of Education is publically available and is housed by DataFirst, an Open Data repository based at the University of Cape Town.

To access the school data (both public and private schools) from this portal follow the link below:
https://www.datafirst.uct.ac.za/dataportal/index.php/catalog/DBE

A note on data quality, there have been some issues highlighted (if I recall in the metadata) about this data.